# Is it possible to have multiple files dao to the same database on android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, koin

I would like to create multiple DAOS files to better organize the project, even though I have only one database. When I try to do something along these lines, it works:

```
@Database(version = 1, entities = [ContaBancaria::class])
abstract class CArchDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun contaBancariaDao(): ContaBancariaDao

    companion object {
        fun createDatabase(context: Context): RoomDatabase {
            return Room.databaseBuilder(context, CArchDatabase::class.java, "CArchDatabase.db")
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .build()
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I try something like this, it doesn't work:

```
@Database(version = 1, entities = [ContaBancaria::class, entity1, entity2,entity3 ....])
abstract class CArchDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun contaBancariaDao(): ContaBancariaDao
    abstract fun dao1(): dao1
    abstract fun dao2(): dao2
    abstract fun dao3(): dao3
    abstract fun dao4(): dao4
    .
    .
    .

    companion object {
        fun createDatabase(context: Context): RoomDatabase {
            return Room.databaseBuilder(context, CArchDatabase::class.java, "CArchDatabase.db")
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .build().dao1().dao2().dao3()....
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using a koin singleton to create my database

```
val cacheDataModule = module {
    single { CArchDatabase.createDatabase(androidContext()) }
    factory<ContaBancariaCacheDataSource> {
        ContaBancariaCacheDataSourceImpl(
            contaBancariaDao = get()
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: `.dao1().dao2().dao3()....` what exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: this is just an attempt, my goal is to have an instance of my database, where I can have multiple @Daos interfaces so that instead of having a big file with more than 1000 lines with multiple queries and inserts in multiple tables I have one file per table.

Comment: All that goes into the Koin modules if you're using Koin. If you don't really understand Koin then don't use Koin (or learn how to use it, I guess, whichever solution you prefer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each one of your database DAO must have a `@Dao` class where operations are defined (check documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room#dao)

From your code I assume you already have a `ContaBancariaDao` class. If you want to create more DAO, you need to create new classes similar to that one.

Then you only need to add a new `fun` in your `CArchDatabase`.

If you also want to add new entities, remember to add them in `entities` array in `@Database` annotation.

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(ContaBancaria::class, Other::class), version = 1)
abstract class CArchDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun contaBancariaDao(): ContaBancariaDao
    abstract fun otherDao(): OtherDao

    companion object {
        fun createDatabase(context: Context): RoomDatabase {
            return Room.databaseBuilder(context, CArchDatabase::class.java, "CArchDatabase.db")
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .build()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried to do this, in my first code example. However I get an error which is " No definition found for class:'br.com.data.local.database.daos.ContaBancariaDao'. Check your definitions!"

Comment: That's a problem with Koin implementation. You are asking for a class (`ContaBancariaDao`) you did not define how to obtain. You did define how to create an instance of `CArchDatabase`, though. 
Simple solution would be to change dependency in `ContaBancariaCacheDataSourceImpl` constructor to receive a `CArchDatabase`. With that you can use `contaBancariaDao()` to get the DAO.